# Given an array containing both positive and negative integers, how to calculate number of pairs whose product is equal to a given clvalue

Tags: c++

I am able to do this in O(n^2) complexity. But I want to know a better solution. I read about assignment of 2 indices start and end and check their product with the given value, but that's not applicable to arrays containing negative integers.

Comment: Why don't split the array into two arrays - one of positive values, and one of negative values - and apply the same more or less solution?

Comment: @ALX23z yeah this sounds good

Comment: don't forget about the case when `clvalue` is negative

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the "array" or to use one of the associative standard containers like `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Is there an upper or lower bound on the numbers? if n is much greater than the possible maximum, you can: (1) sort the array (nlogn), (2) iterate i from -sqrt(clvalue) to +sqrt(clvalue), check if clvalue/i exists.

Comment: @ALX23z comment will be helpful to speed up checking if clvalue/i  exists.

Comment: @Bob__ you are allowed to sort the array